# How do you trap Ctrl-C in the Leiningen REPL?

Tags: clojure, signals, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

How can you trap Ctrl-C in the Leiningen REPL?

`set-break-handler!` seems to have no effect:

```
user=> (set-break-handler! (fn [sig] (println "HERE!" sig)))
#object[clojure.repl.proxy$java.lang.Object$SignalHandler$d8c00ec7 0x22e61b57
  "clojure.repl.proxy$java.lang.Object$SignalHandler$d8c00ec7@22e61b57"]
user=>
```

That funny character after the second prompt (if you can see it) is ASCII 3. That's what appeared when I hit Ctrl-C. It appears that Leiningen has disabled the connection between Ctrl-C and the SIGINT signal. (This is on a Linux system.) Leiningen treats the Ctrl-C as just another character. If I hit Enter, the Clojure compiler complains that it can't resolve the symbol . (Again, you might not be able to see it; Ctrl-C is not a printable glyph in most fonts.)

The reason I want this is so I can run some code that I'm experimenting with as an infinite loop, see what it does for a while, stop it, change it a bit, try it again, and so on. I don't actually want to set the INT-handler by calling `set-break-handler` directly at the REPL. I want to put it into my code so it cleans up its threads and kills its subprocess.

---

By the way, I thought I'd see if Leiningen is messing with my stty settings, so I typed this:

```
user=> (clojure.java.shell/sh "stty" "-a")
{:exit 1, :out "", :err "stty: standard input: Invalid argument\n"}
```

What?? `stty -a` works fine if I type it at the shell prompt. Is this a clue to the problem?